# Ejecutar una variable pública en un método estático

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

¿Hay alguna posibilidad de llamar a una variable con esto en una función estática?. ¿Tengo que crear algún paso intermedio para lograrlo?. Lo que quiero hacer es llamar a esa función en otra clase

```js
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
       this.address = this.navParams.get('address');
       this.options = this.navParams.get('options');
       this.snap = this.navParams.get('address');
   }

    public static cancel_editable() {
     this.address = this.snap;
  }
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, traduce tu pregunta, el idioma oficial del sitio es el "español", saludos.

Comment: Lo siento, ya esta hecho :)

Comment: No entiendo qué quieres conseguir, si el método es estático no está asociado a ningún objeto. Si va a estar asociado a un objeto, puedes crearlo como no estático. Si quieres que un método estático realice una acción sobre un objeto en particular, pásaselo como parámetro.